# How to specify batch-size of tasks that celery workers can accept?

Tags: parallel-processing, celery, gpu

I'm trying to design a system where the caller sends data to celery workers which run on GPU machines, they do some processing and return the results to the caller. Since GPUs can process a batch-full of data in parallel (say N items in parallel), it makes sense for the celery task to accept N items of data and process all N items together.

On the caller side, I am able to use [chunks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chunks) to break apart my list of data items into sublists of some fixed `BATCH_SIZE`.

```
 job = tasks.predict.chunks(texts, BATCH_SIZE)
 result = job.apply_async()
```

However, my issue is that I would like to specify the `BATCH_SIZE` on the receiving end (worker) instead of the caller, because each worker may have a different limit on the number of data items it can process in one batch (because GPU memory size can vary across different workers).

What's the best way to go about doing this? I want the celery worker to be able to consume an arbitrary N items from the data workload during a single task.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably the best that each Worker has BATCH_SIZE in its configuration. Your tasks can then easily grab this value from the config.

Comment: That's a good angle but then my question is - what should the tasks do with that BATCH_SIZE value? How can a task request for N items from the celery queue?

Comment: That should be controlled by however you run your Celery worker - it should have concurrency level configured with however you specify. In my case we run Celery as systemd service and shell script analyses the environment (number of CPU cores and memory) and sets up the concurrency value.

Comment: Thanks @DejanLekic but I think i'm still not getting it - If I set a concurrency as N then that would mean that there are N *tasks* running concurrently.. How do I instead collect N *data items* into a single task - so that i can batch them all together in a single GPU request?

Comment: One solution that comes to my mind is to have an additional internal queue inside the celery worker, so the tasks can pool the data into that single queue, and then a separate background task/thread would consume the right amount of data per batch. But this feels like i'm reimplementing the whole celery queue system :) .. and I wish there was a more obvious/direct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it currently is through the not-so-friendly [celery-batches](https://github.com/clokep/celery-batches) package. The example of use is in the deprecated [celery.contrib.batches](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/reference/celery.contrib.batches.html) package.

With model prediction, you currently should have something wrapped in a context class such as:

```python
class Context(Task):
    def __init__(self):
        self._model = get_model()

@app.task(base=Context)
def predict(img):
    return predict._model(img)
```

With `celery-batches`, you rewrite your model as:

```python
class Context(Batches):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Context, self).__init__()
        self._model = get_batch_model()

@app.task(base=Context,
          flush_every=BATCH_SIZE,
          flush_interval=MAX_IDLE_TIME)
def predict(requests):
    batch = []
    for request in requests:
        batch.append(request.args[0])
    reponses = predict_batched(predict._model, batch)
    for response, request in zip(reponses, requests):
        app.backend.mark_as_done(request.id, response)

def predict_batched(model, batch):
    return model(batch)
```

where BATCH_SIZE can be defined individually in each worker, and your worker will process either when it accumulates BATCH_SIZE tasks, or when MAX_IDLE_TIME has passed.